# Como abrir uma activity a partir de um calculo?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

Sou bem leigo em android studio e preciso fazer um programa sobre um calculo de IMC. A idéia é simples, na primeira activity ele pede o seu peso e sua altura, após isso ele deve fazer a conta do imc (imc = peso/altura²) e se o resultado for menor que 20 ele abre uma activity, se for maior que 30 ele abre uma outra e se estiver entre 20 e 30 ele abre uma 4ª activity. Alguem pode me ajudar com essa função?

Answer (score 1):

Só usar if com o resultado da conta:

```
    double imc = peso / Math.pow(altura,2)
if (imc <20 ){
Intent tela1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tela1.class);
            startActivity(tela1);
}else if(imc > 30 ){
Intent tela2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tela2.class);
            startActivity(tela2);
}else if(imc>=20 && imc <=30){
Intent tela3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tela3.class);
            startActivity(tela3);
}
```

Isso dentro do click do botao calcular.
A lógica é essa, espero ter ajudado